# Is there a word for 'everything' in the Northern English dialect?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, dialects

I'm wondering if there's a word for *everything* in the Northern-English dialect that's spoken in and around Yorkshire.

I know that there's *summat* (something), *owt* (anything), and *nowt* (nothing), but is there a Northern-English word that follows the same pattern and means *everything*? (And is generally considered as an equivalent member of this family of constructions?)

Comment: Yes, they have a word for everything. :)

Comment: More seriously, some of these forms show up in southern Scottish as well as northern English, and unless you have a native speaker of either to tell you which ones do or do not get used in a particular region, it may be rather hard to pin down.  Certainly various varieties of Scots have words that they **do** use where we would use *everything*, like [here](https://stooryduster.co.uk/scottish-words-glossary/index.htm) and [here](https://stooryduster.co.uk/scottish-words-glossary/words-i.htm).

Comment: @tchrist - please post answers in the answer box and not as a comment!! Thanks

Comment: @user66974 tchrist’s comments are not answers but are relevant comment and interesting.

Answer (score 6):

I know of no similar word for “everything”. I doubt it exists. Here is the well known (locally at least) Yorkshireman’s motto:

> [Historic UK](https://www.historic-uk.com/CultureUK/Yorkshire-Dialect/)
> *Ear all, see all, say nowt;
>
> Eat all, sup all, pay nowt;
>
> And if ivver tha does owt fer nowt –
>
> Allus do it fer thissen.*

Loosely translated, this is:
*Hear everything, see everything, say nothing

Eat everything, drink everything, pay nothing

And if ever you do anything for nothing

Always do it for yourself*

If there were a word for “everything”, it would surely appear in this caricaturing ditty. It does not, so the likelihood is that no such word is in common use. And I never heard one during my upbringing in deepest Yorkshire.

I often heard *all* as in constructions such as:
*Has tha go’ all’us tha needs?*
Meaning
*Have you got all (everything) that you need?*

(Note: “all” is pronounced with a short “a”, as in “as” rather than in “fall”. Forgive my ignorance of phonetic symbolism.)

Comment: There's a 't' at the end of "has" and an 'r' sound between "go'" and "all" in my experience giving "hast tha gorall as tha needs?" I don't know IPA either.

Comment: @BoldBen agreed. I feel the “t” and the “r” are somewhere between silence and full expression so I do not dispute in any way what you say. Tha’s reet.

Comment: Interesting! "*All'us*" sounds almost exactly like the Dutch "*alles*", which means 'everything'.

Comment: @Joachim Yes, "All" is related to Dutch/German "alles" and similar Scandinavian words. But I always understood "all'us" as a form of " all as is", meaning "all that is". For example "Bring all'us necessary" = "Bring all as is necessary" = "Bring all that is necessary". But we are delving deep into my memory, which is not always reliable!

Comment: @Anton tha's reet an' all! Mind you the 't' at the end of 'hast' is there because Yorkshire, Derbyshire and other dialects never abandoned the second person singular.

Comment: @BoldBen always a treat exchanging views with you. Might even enjoy a drink at Tickton one day!

Comment: Cheers Anton! You're prob right, though 'summat' doesn't appear in that extract and so it's possible there is an obscure Northern English word for everything.

Answer (score 2):

I am from Yorkshire and nothing comes to mind, but then again I'm not familiar with older Yorkshire dialects.

We do sometimes use "lot" to mean all/everything/any which is informal but I don't think that it is only used in Northern English(?).

I'll give you three quid for the *lot* (everything)

I don't like the *lot* of them (any)

All the moves were terrible, the whole *lot* of them (all)

source: me

Comment: Yeh, 'the lot' or 'the whole lot' is labelled only as informal by the Oxford Dictionary.